# Should I use asObservable in BehaviorSubject?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am wondering what is the two approach in the following code in `BehaviorSubject`.

As far as I know:

> The asObservable method not only cast it to an Observable, it also removes the Observer implementation. Therefore you are not able to call next, error & complete on the instance returned by asObservable().

but the following also makes me confused:

> By only exposing asObservable you can consume the values emitted but prevent from making changes to the BehaviorSubject from outside the service where this BehaviorSubject was created. For this reason use asObservable().

Is there anything wrong with these definitions?

```
export class DataService {

    // usage I : using getter
    private messageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

    getMessage(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
        return this.messageSubject;
    }

    setMessage(param: any): void {
        this.messageSubject.next(param);
    }


    // usage II : using asObservable()
    private messageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);
    
    currentMessage = this.messageSubject.asObservable();

    setMessage(param: any) {
    this.messageSubject.next(param)
    }
}
```

Which approach above is better to use or what is the pros and cons for these 2 approaches?

**Update:** Last time I finalised the correct usage as the following:

```
// usage III : using @martin's approach:
private messageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);
    
public messages$: Observable<any> = this.messageSubject;

//should I set the observable still using the following method without any changing? Or do I need an update?
setMessage(param: any) {
    this.messageSubject.next(param)
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the recommended way of doing this in TypeScript is only by type casting like this:

```
private messageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

public messages$: Observable<any> = this.messageSubject;
```

This way it's TypeScript compiler who won't let you call `next()`, `error()` or `complete()`. Using `asObservable()` is recommened only when using RxJS in pure JavaScript. For example, internally in RxJS source code it never uses `asObservable()` even though it uses and exposes Subjects => Observables a lot.

For more info see discussion: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2408

Comment: So, do you mean that I should use the **usage II** by **just** changing `currentMessage = this.messageSubject.asObservable();` to `public messages$: Observable<any> = this.messageSubject;`?

Comment: On the other hand what is the differences between usage I and II in my example?

Comment: In the first example you're returning `BehaviorSubject` and yes you can use just `public messages$: Observable<any> = this.messageSubject;`

Comment: Thank you very much. In this case can I use next(), error() or complete() ? If so, will be be a disadvantage to use it as in your suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can call this on the `BehaviorSubject` instance.

Comment: See my Update please. I asked "should I set the observable still using the following method without any changing? Or do I need an update?" in that update.

Comment: By calling `this.messageSubject.next` you're not setting anything. It's still the same `BehaviorSubject` and `messages$` is the same Observable. `next()` will propagate a single value down the chain to all observers. So you don't need to resubscribe to `messages$` because it's still the same object.

Comment: In this case I can get the value by calling `messages$` variable in my update (usage III). But how can I set this variable if I do not use setMessage?

Comment: You can use `this.messageSubject.next(param)`

Comment: Sorry Martin, but I had already used it in my Update. But I could not understand your comments after my "See my Update please..." comment. So, can we say that correct usage that you suggest is exactly the usage in my Update section in the question?

Comment: Yes, you still need to be able to call next() and you’re calling it on the Subject instace which is correct.

Comment: When using `public messages$: Observable<any> = this.messageSubject;` can I use next(), error() or complete() ? If not, will it be a disadvantage to use it as in your suggestion?

Comment: You can use all of them on `this.messageSubject`. They'll be propagated by `messages$` like with any other Observable.