# Is there a reason to use getters and setters to access Subjects within service rather than accessing directly?

Tags: angular, rxjs

While going through the documentation for NgBootstraps Table component, I noticed that they use getters and setters to access their Subjects from a service.
See example here:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/table/complete/stackblitz.html
in the `country.service.ts`

I have always just directly subscribed to services from my other components. ie rather than using a

```
 get countries$() { return this._countries$.asObservable(); }
```

I'd just read `this._countryService._countries$`, and subscribe to it or use async pipe as needed.

Is it a better practise to use getters and setters like this?

Comment: The main advantage I see here is that other components that are subscribing just see an `Observable<T>` instead of a `Subject<T>`, as they should not care that it is a `Subject<T>`. In other words, this is just an example of encapsulation.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61288259/9287029, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36986548/9287029, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65121970/should-i-use-asobservable-in-behaviorsubject

Comment: Is there a reason? Sure! Are there good reasons: debatable. Mostly I'd call it person style. And although I don't like his / her variable naming, its still the same thing: Personal choices and objectives more than anything concrete